# using predictInterval function in merTools

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I have a question regarding the `predictInterval` function in `merTools` package in R. Here's an example
data.

```
library(lme4)
library(ISLR)
data(Auto)
mdl<-lmer(mpg ~ horsepower + I(horsepower^2) + displacement + I(displacement^2) + (1|name) + (1|year),data=Auto)
```

With this model, I want to predict for the values of `horesepower` while keeping `displacement` at its mean value.

I make a new dataframe called `auto1`.

```
auto1<-Auto
auto1$displacement <- mean(auto1$displacement)

PI <- predictInterval(merMod = mdl, newdata = auto1,level = 0.95, n.sims = 1000, stat = "median",include.resid.var = TRUE)
```

My question is: Do I have to also specify the mean values of `displacement` quadratic term 
`I(displacement^2)` or does R internally uses the `auto1$displacement` to work out `I(displacement^2)` in the predict function.

Same for `horsepower`. Do I separately need to specify the quadratic values  `horsepower` 
or does R uses `horsepower` internally to work our `I(horsepower^2)`.

Thanks

Comment: As of the newest version of `merTools` (0.3.0) the package should handle this automatically for you.